# How to get to this result $ (\mu_2-\mu_1)^{´}V^{-1}\bigl( \frac{\mu_2+\mu_1 }{2}\bigr)=0$ using matrix operations?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, algebra-precalculus, statistics, multivariate-statistical-analysis

In the book, $\mu_1$ and $\mu_{2}$ are a vector with dimension , $p\times 1$ y $V^{-1}$ inverse covariance matrix with dimension $p\times p$. I have the following identity

$$ \frac{1}{2}\mu_{1}^{´}V^{-1}\mu_1= -\frac{1}{2}\mu_2^{´}V^{-1}\mu_2 $$
$$ (\mu_2-\mu_1)^{´}V^{-1}\bigl( \frac{\mu_2+\mu_1 }{2}\bigr)=0$$

and the textbook omits the steps it has taken to arrive at this result.
Someone could develop it. I have tried to use the usual properties of matrices, Distributivity, Transpose, etc. but nothing

Comment: Do you mean that you want to prove that the first equation  implies the second ?

Comment: I find $\frac{1}{2}\mu_{1}^{´}V^{-1}\mu_1= \color{red}{+}\frac{1}{2}\mu_2^{´}V^{-1}\mu_2 \implies (\mu_2-\mu_1)^{´}V^{-1}\bigl( \frac{\mu_2+\mu_1 }{2}\bigr)=0$ by expansion of the LHS of the target equality (remember that $\mu_2'V^{-1}\mu_1=\mu_1'V^{-1}\mu_2$ because matrix $V^{-1}$ is symmetric, and the result is a number, equal to its transpose)

Comment: Any comment about the suppression of minus sign ?

Comment: I just came home. I did not remember that property of symmetric matrices. Now, I did understand. Thank you